# Strange performance from RAID5 using WD RE4 disks

Tags: hard-drive, performance, raid

I've noticed a bit of a performance issue with some WD RE4 drives I'm using under AMD's hardware RAID solution. First a bit of background:

- Environment: Windows 7 home premium x64
- HDD's: 3x 1TB WD Raid Edition 4 in a RAID 5 setup with 128 kbyte stripe (2TB usable space)
- Testing Tool: HD Tune, process set to "High Priority"
- Processor: AMD Phenom II x6 1100T
- Ram: 16GB DDR3/1600mhz
- Motherboard: MSI 970A-G45

The image below pretty much depicts the issue I'm having. Every test has the same thing, a period of similar length where the performance drops to a few megabytes a second. This can't be a TLER issue as the purpose of RE4's is to work around that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You might also want to look into `WDIDLE3` and the head park times for your computer.  It has nothing to do with this test (since the heads obviously aren't parked), but it's an issue you should consider with these new WD hard drives (I personally just disabled head parking on my desktop).

Comment: Thanks Breakthrough, I could only find it for the RE2-GP, is that still applicable for RE4? The only bit of information I could find is that this *could* be that I'm using onboard RAID versus installing a RAID card. Could the onboard RAID be causing this?

Comment: yes, the tool works with those drives as well (I used it on my brand new Caviar Green EARS-model, it worked on my older Caviar Blacks as well - although head parking was disabled on those already).  I doubt that using the onboard RAID is the issue here (assuming all driver/BIOS updates have been done), especially if it supports RAID-5 under hardware.

Comment: Another issue I run into, RAIDXpert's Sync/Fix option or media patrol never go beyond 0%. They do however put an interesting tidbit in the events log "Synchronization is requested to perform on the logical drive "RE4Array " that has never been initialized." which doesn't make sense. This coupled with random "Unknown event"'s that pop up occasionally, I have no clue what this RAID setup is doing. Unknown event's also occured for 2x Caviar Black's in a RAID 0 setup.

Comment: @Howard - could you please post the screenshots for the other three tabs?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem? Synchronization might make sense as to keep the parity fine, perhaps it's behind on something and first needs the synchronization done before it can continue with the rest. It would be nice to see the other tabs. Are there any RAID driver or software for your system and have you tried those?

Comment: What is "AMD's hardware RAID solution"? Outside of server boards pretty much all motherboard based RAID is software. A bit in BIOS to let you create and boot from the array plus drivers/detection in Windows itself to use it once it is booted.

Comment: I am still having issues, found more issues with the processor and tracked it down. This motherboard was discontinued due to a VRM issue, MSI is issuing me a replacement motherboard / upgrade (MSI 970A-G46) which they insist will resolve the issues. The additional issue I found was pushing the CPU to it's max resulted in a faulty readout of 255ºC on the CPU and a clock from 3.3GHZ to 800MHZ (16.5x multiplier to 4.0) - I'll report back when this has been confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note that the AMD RAID solution in the SB950 is not a "hardware RAID" solution.

The message about the array not being initialised would indicate that the array is initialized in background, there is nothing intrinsically wrong with this, but performance should improve when initialisation has completed.